# Fetching multiple table data using spring and hibernate not working as excepted in UI-Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, servlets

I have three tables they are **Forum**,**ForumAnswer** and **ForumAnswerReplay**. this table contains `@OneToMany` relationship. I have Forum table primary key. Based on that primary key I need to get `ForumAnswer` and `ForumAnswerReplay` data.

[image: In this image contains my reponse.but not reached response to UI]

But response is not reaching `ui side`.

**Stack Trace**

> ResponseStatusExceptionResolver:133 - Resolving exception from handler
>   [public java.util.List
>   com.tta.abcd.controller.ForumController.getReplayToAnswer(javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)]:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
>   Could not write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)

**Forum.java**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Forum")
    public class Forum {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="forumId")
    private Long forumId;

    @Column(name="question")
    private String question;

    @Column(columnDefinition="varchar(1000)",name="discription")
    private String discription;

    @Column(name="postedDate")
    private Date postedDate;

    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "forumId")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<ForumAnswer> forumList;
    }
```

**ForumAnswer.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ForumAnswer")
public class ForumAnswer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="forumAnswerId")
    private Long forumAnswerId;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "forumId",insertable=true, updatable=true,nullable=true)
    private Forum forum;

    @Column(name="answer")
    private String answer;

    @Column(name="answerDate")
    private Date answerDate;

    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "forumAnswerId")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<ForumAnswerReplay> forumAnswerReplayList;
    }
```

**ForumAnswerReplay.java**

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="ForumAnswerReplay")
 public class ForumAnswerReplay {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="replayId")
    private Long replayId;

    @Column(name="replayToAnswer")
    private String replayToAnswer;

    @Column(name="replayToAnswerDate")
    private Date replayToAnswerDate;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="forumAnswerId",insertable=true,updatable=true,nullable=true)
    @JsonBackReference
    private ForumAnswer forumAnswer;
    }
```

**Controller Code:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getForumOnIdAnswer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public List<ForumAnswer> getForumAnswerOnId(@RequestBody Long id, HttpSession session,
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    List<ForumAnswer> forumAnswer = forumService.getForumAnswerOnId(id);
    if (forumAnswer != null) {
        return forumAnswer;
    }
    return forumAnswer;
}
```

**DAO:**

```
public List<ForumAnswer> getForumAnswerOnId(Long id) {
    Long forumId = id;
    List<ForumAnswer> ForumAnswerTemp = new ArrayList<ForumAnswer>();
    List<ForumAnswerReplay> ForumAnswerReplayTemp = new ArrayList<ForumAnswerReplay>();
    Long forumAnswerId = null;
    ForumAnswer forumTemp = new ForumAnswer();
    ForumAnswer forumEntity = new ForumAnswer();


    String getForumAnswer = "from ForumAnswer WHERE forumId =:forumId order by answerDate Desc";
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(getForumAnswer);
    query.setParameter("forumId", forumId);

    List<ForumAnswer> forumList = query.list();
    int count =forumList.size();
    if ( count> 0) {
        for (int i=1 ; i < count ;i++) {
            forumEntity =forumList.get(i);
            forumAnswerId = forumList.get(i).getForumAnswerId();
            List<ForumAnswerReplay> repltList = getreplayList(forumAnswerId);
            if (repltList.size() > 0) {
                ForumAnswerReplayTemp.addAll(repltList);
                forumEntity.setForumAnswerReplayList(ForumAnswerReplayTemp);
                ForumAnswerTemp.add(forumEntity);
            } else {
                ForumAnswerTemp.add(forumEntity);
            }
        }
    }
    return ForumAnswerTemp;
}

public List<ForumAnswerReplay> getreplayList(Long forumAnswerId) {
    String getForumAnswer = "from ForumAnswerReplay WHERE forumAnswerId =:forumAnswerId";
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(getForumAnswer);
    query.setParameter("forumAnswerId", forumAnswerId);
    List<ForumAnswerReplay> replays = query.list();
    return replays;

}
```

Comment: I think you need to retreive `owner` values to UI..?

Comment: Do you have all the required jars for Jackson?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan ya i have all the required Jackson jars

Comment: Resolving exception from handler [public java.util.List<com.tta.abcd.model.ForumAnswer> com.tta.abcd.controller.ForumController.getForumAnswerOnId(java.lang.Long,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

Comment: Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to use @Transactional annotation on your impl class.

One of the key points about @Transactional is that there are two separate concepts to consider, each with it's own scope and life cycle:

the persistence context
the database transaction
The transactional annotation itself defines the scope of a single database transaction. The database transaction happens inside the scope of apersistence context.

The persistence context is in JPA the EntityManager, implemented internally using an Hibernate Session (when using Hibernate as the persistence provider).

The persistence context is just a synchronizer object that tracks the state of a limited set of Java objects and makes sure that changes on those objects are eventually persisted back into the database.

This is a very different notion than the one of a database transaction. One Entity Manager can be used across several database transactions, and it actually often is.

https://dzone.com/articles/how-does-spring-transactional

Comment: I'm using @Transactional in class level. that is not a problem.i have both query values in 'ForumAnswerTemp' but response is not going to ui side

Answer (score 0):

Make return type String in your method deceleration and Convert your list to map and create Model object and set your map in model. then return to your desire jsp page.

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/getForumOnIdAnswer", method = RequestMethod.POST)

```
public String yourList(@RequestBody Long id, Model model){

    List<ForumAnswer> forumAnswer = forumService.getForumAnswerOnId(id);
    if (forumAnswer != null) {

        // convert your list to Map then set in model. 
            model.addAttribute("forumAnswerMap",listToMap);
    }
    return "yourJspPage"
`
```

May be it will help you..